# Как установить лимит для использования команды одним пользователем discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Я хочу чтобы бот создавал приватный текстовый канал (канал видит только его создатель). Я уже сделал чтобы бот при прописывании команды создавал приватный канал, но эту команду можно использовать бесконечно. Я хочу чтобы это можно было сделать только 1 раз. Я предполагаю что это надо работать с файлами(записывать в файл и читать), но я новичок и не могу, посмотрел в интернете: не чего не понял.

```
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
bot.remove_command( 'help' ) #удаление стандартной команды
token = 'Мой токен'


@bot.command()
async def приват(ctx):
    #Выдача прав на канал
    overwrites = {
        ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    } 
    userName = ctx.author
    nameChannelbefore = "╎"
    after = str(nameChannelbefore) + str(userName) #переменная с именем канала (╎ник)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(after, overwrites=overwrites) #создание канала


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot started...')
bot.run(token)
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Могу предложить такой алгоритм работы:**

1. При использовании команды, пользователь записывается в массив, а его id - в текстовый файл
2. При запуске бота, считываем id пользователей из файла и добавляем в тот же массив

Поскольку вторым пунктом будет заниматься бот, алгоритм нужно поместить в функцию `on_ready()`, когда бот уже будет готов к получению пользователей.

**В итоге, получаем что-то такое:**

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'token'

# массив пользователей, использовавших команду
used_users = []

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # проверяем, существует ли текстовый файл, хранящий id. Если нет - создаем.
    if not os.path.exists('used_users.txt'):
        with open('used_users.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.close()
    
    # открываем файл в режиме чтения и считываем все строки в список
    with open('used_users.txt', 'r') as file:
        ids = file.readlines()
        for i in range(0, len(ids)):
            # в цикле от нуля до количества пользователей считываем их id и добавляем в массив
            used_users.append(await bot.fetch_user(int(ids[i])))

# сюда подставьте свою команду
@bot.command()
async def my_command(ctx):
    # получаем автора сообщения
    author = ctx.message.author

    # если автора нет в списке, то выполняем команду и заносим в список
    if author not in used_users:

        await ctx.send('Команда выполнена! Использования осталось: 0')
        used_users.append(author)
        with open('used_users.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(f'{author.id}\n')
            
    else:
        await ctx.send('Вы **НЕ** имеете право на выполнение данной команды')


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, помните, что событие "on_ready" может вызываться более чем один раз:

`Warning: This function is not guaranteed to be the first event called. Likewise, this function is not guaranteed to only be called once. This library implements reconnection logic and thus will end up calling this event whenever a RESUME request fails.`

Comment: @Fixator10, в таком случае, стоит добавить условие, при котором будет выполняться считывание id из файлов в `on_ready()`, чтобы при повторном вызове этого уже не происходило