# Как сделать чтобы участник дискорд сервера мог вводить команду несколько раз в день на python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я написал бота и добавил ему команду. Мне нужно чтобы участник(с определённой ролью(проверку если ли у участника "эта" роль я уже сделал)) дискорд сервера мог вводить эту команду только несколько раз в день(допустим 3). Как это сделать? Python discord.py

Comment: Возможно вот, что вы ищите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201658/Как-установить-лимит-для-использования-команды-одним-пользователем-discord-py

Comment: iframe, то что вы скинули не много не то. Я отредактировал описание вопроса, чтобы было ещё понятнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используем [`@commands.cooldown()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)

Код:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(3, 10, commands.BucketType.role)
async def somethink(ctx):
    ...
```

3 - количесто раз использувания команды
10 - секунд до перезарядки команды
[`commands.BucketType.role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.BucketType) - на что будет реагировать `cooldown`